# NodeJS Passport Autehntication Bad Request

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to follow a tutorial video on how to use passport with node but for some reason I keep getting a bad request error, I tried some of the example on passport's site, including the custom callbacks as well as some suggestions from forums but no luck. It seems that the program is not even calling passport.use (i tried putting a console message but it doesn't come up at all).

**passport-config:**

```
module.exports = function(){
    var passport = require('passport');
    var passportLocal = require('passport-local');
    var userService = require('../services/user-service');

    passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy({usernameField: 'email'}, function(email, password, next){

        console.log('========TEST=======');

        userService.findUser(email, function(err, user){

            if(user){
                console.log(user.email + ' found!');
            }

            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            if(!user || user.password != password){
                return next(null,false);
            }
            next(null, user);
        });
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, next){
        next(null, user.email);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(email, next){
        userService.findUser(email, function(err, user){
            next(err, user);
        });
    });
};
```

**User route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userService = require('../services/user-service');
var passport = require('passport');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('users', {
    title: 'Users',
    description: 'This is the users page'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users/login', {
    title: 'Login',
    description: 'Please login'
  });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/items');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**user-service:**

```
var User = require('../models/user').User;

exports.addUser = function(user, next){
    var newUser = new User({
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        email: user.email.toLowerCase(),
        password: user.password
    });

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        next(null);
    });
};

exports.findUser = function(email, next){
    User.findOne({email: email.toLowerCase()}, function(err, user){
      next(err, user);
    });
};
```

**www**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('main');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var config = require('./config.js');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var items = require('./routes/items');

var passportConfig = require('./auth/passport-config');
passportConfig();


mongoose.connect(config.mongoUri);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(expressSession(
  {
    secret: 'I will achieve my GOALS!',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
  }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/items/', items);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Where's your server itself? Can you add whatever JS file is starting the server?

Comment: This is running on localhost, it's the default express generated files for node.

Comment: I've added www and app.js

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your passport variable in your app.js file to use your config instead of the passport module.

```
var passport = require('./auth/passport-config');
```

Remove the following from app.js

```
var passportConfig = require('./auth/passport-config');
passportConfig();
```